# Numpy Array in object instance, dtype error

Tags: python, numpy, dtype

While trying to pack my working python code into classes, I encountered a dtype error that I cannot get my head around.

My python knowledge is quiet limited, so I don´t know if this is common practice, but I use some imports in my class.

```
class Analyzer:

    import math
    import numpy as np
    from saxpy.alphabet import cuts_for_asize
    from saxpy.paa import paa
    from saxpy.znorm import znorm
    from saxpy.sax import ts_to_string

    def __init__(self, sensorConfig):
        self.sensorConfig = sensorConfig

    ...

    def normalizePaaAndSaxData(self, paaSteps, saxAlphabetLen, sensorValues):
        norm = self.znorm(self.np.array(sensorValues))
        paaV = self.paa(norm, paaSteps)
        saxV = self.ts_to_string(paaV, self.cuts_for_asize(saxAlphabetLen))
        return zip(paaV, saxV)
```

The numpy library is the problematic one. When I use np.array(someValues) outside a class, then numpy automatically chooses float64 as dtype. But in a class it crashes with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TestPaaAndSax.py", line 38, in <module>
    analyzer.getEvents(values)
  File "C:\Users\pasca\git\BeamMeScotty\app\src\Analyzer.py", line 39, in getEvents
    sensorValues)
  File "C:\Users\pasca\git\BeamMeScotty\app\src\Analyzer.py", line 43, in normalizePaaAndSaxData
    norm = self.znorm(self.np.array(sensorValues, dtype=self.np.float64))
  File "C:\Users\pasca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\saxpy\znorm.py", line 7, in znorm
    sd = np.std(series)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in std
  File "C:\Users\pasca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 3497, in std
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pasca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 234, in _std
    keepdims=keepdims)
  File "C:\Users\pasca\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 197, in _var
    arrmean = arrmean.dtype.type(arrmean / rcount)
AttributeError: 'Analyzer' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

From research I got the info, that the dtype specifies the type of values in the array. Unfortunately I´m not able to set this, even by hand.

```
norm = self.znorm(self.np.array(sensorValues, dtype=self.np.float64))
```

Hope you can help me with that!

Greetings Pascal

Comment: Did you try `dtype=np.float64` instead of `dtype=self.np.float64`

Comment: I tried that, but I need the self cause it´s an import in a class and not in a file